# Feature selection in regression with ARMA errors

Tags: forecasting, feature-selection, arima

I am working on creating a forecast of an `auto.arima` model with predictors. I consider an exploratory first step of creating simple regression models, like the example I have in the code below*, in order to find good predictors to use in the `auto.arima` model. Would that make sense?

*(`lm` is just a place holder in this example, it could be some other form of simple regression like `glm`.)

Code:

```
##Simple Regression Model
fit1<-lm(series~df$Predictor1, df)
    fit2<-lm(series~df$Predictor2, df)

##Compare Regression Models
anova(fit1,fit2)

##Partitioning Data
Train <-series[1:700]
Validation <- series[701:1000]


Xreg<-df$Predictor1[1:1000]

##Predictor
xregTrain <- Xreg[1:700]
xregVal <- Xreg[701:1000]


fit <- auto.arima(Train, xreg = xregTrain)

Fcast<-forecast(fit, h=300, xreg = xregVal)
```

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 3):

Partial bivariate regressions are generally not a good idea for variable selection. This has been pointed out repeatedly in different posts (curiously, I cannot find any of them to cite right now, even though I remember quite well reading a few). Regression with ARMA errors (which is what is produced by `auto.arima` with external regressors -- see Rob J. Hyndman's blog post ["The ARIMAX model muddle"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/)) should not be an exception.

What are the alternatives?

1. All subset selection in regression with ARMA errors, where performance of the different models is evaluated using cross validation. This could be computationally infeasible if the number of variables is large. Also, the method may be prone to overfitting and biased estimates just as in the case of regression without ARMA errors.
2. Penalized estimation of regression with ARMA errors. This could be more useful and perhaps less computationally intensive than the above option, but I am not aware of software implementations for penalized regression with ARMA errors.
3. If the effect of ARMA errors is not too strong, perhaps you could do penalized multiple regression to find the relevant variables and then do regression with ARMA errors using the selected set of regressors.